# 'I, too, am waiting ...' and 'I, also, am waiting ...'

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, punctuation, too-also

> Kitty: I'm waiting for a banana.
>
> Jair: I, *too*, am waiting for a banana. (1)
>
> Jair: I, *also*, am waiting for a banana. (2)

Which is correct, (1) or (2)? If both, what's the difference? Plus, are commas before and after too/also strictly required?

Comment: I am also is more heard than I also am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these are correct in formal English, but they don't reflect actual speech.

*Also* is comparatively rare in speech, and almost never to specify that the subject is 'duplicated'. As Mistu4u tells you, it is usually placed immediately before a single lexical verb or immediately after the first auxiliary, regardless of whether it is the verb or the complement that it duplicates:

> I have a banana, and I'm also waiting for a banana.
>   I have a banana, and I also have an orange.
>   I have a banana, and I've also been promised an orange.

*Too* is far more frequent, and it's almost always set at the end of the clause, regardless of which constituent is duplicated:

> You have a banana, and I have a banana, too.
>   I have a banana, and I'm waiting for a banana, too.
>   I have a banana, and I have an orange, too.

By orthographic convention *too* is set off with commas wherever it falls; *also* is not set off unless it falls in an unusual place.