# Should I say "also surprised" or "surprised too"?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, word-order, too-also

Is this sentence correct?  Does it sound ok for a native English speaker?

> Are you **also** surprised?

I'm asking because I'm not a native English speaker. I'm not sure if it sounds natural. 
I would use

> "Are you surprised **too**."

instead, but I'd like to know if it sounds ok with "also" too.

Comment: Tom, can you describe what research you've done and your current understanding of how and when to use *also*? Is there a particular reason you are unsure if this sentence is correct?

Comment: Helo and welcome to the site! Please note: Simple proofreading is off-topic for this site and leads to your qustion being closed rather quickly. But if you have a *specific* point that you are wondering about, please edit your question and we'll be happy to add our own "five cents" to it.

Comment: I'm asking because I'm not a native English speaker.  I'm not sure if it sounds natural.  I would use "Are you surprised too." instead, but I'd like to know if it sounds ok with also too.

Comment: We sort of assumed this ;-) (neither am I, btw.) @pyobum gave some good pointers and if you need more, see [this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) post on ELL meta which I personally think every new user should read.

Comment: Related (and this question is possibly a duplicate): http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16421/too-vs-also-which-one-is-correct, http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10718/too-vs-also-in-i-too-and-i-also.

Comment: Another option: *Are you surprised as well?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are ok, but your first sentence is more written than spoken.

"Also is commonly used in writing, but is less common in speaking." (Source: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/also-as-well-or-too)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Can you give a reference for yor statement? Are you a native speaker? Generally, it's a good idea to back up your answers a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Unspoken, they mean pretty much the the same thing. But when spoken, the emphasis would typically be different, and that can produce a difference in interpretation because it makes the "too" or "also" agree with either "surprised" (first form) or "you" (second form). So:

"Are you also *surprised*?" could mean what it does in the following:

> "So, you're angry, and you're upset, and you're frustrated. Are you also surprised?

"Are *you* surprised *too*?" could mean what it does in the following:

> "Well I'm surprised, and Paul is surprised, and I'm pretty sure Betty is surprised. Are you surprised too?"